# Heavily reducing memory usage in django, how to safely use .only() and .defer()

Tags: python, django

For most projects, the heaviest load on memory is when big data queries are loaded into python memory, like

```
Model.objects.filter(...).order_by(...)[:50] 
# The second [:50] is evaluated, the entire dataset is shoved into memory.
```

In the django docs: the [.defer()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer) and [.only()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) queryset methods are mentioned as tips
to help reduce memory usage, but not much more is mentioned about them.

I guess my main question is, when trying to .save() or .delete() model instances, is it ok to just call it on a model with everything deferred except the pk?
Ex:

```
model = Model.objects.only("pk").get(pk=12)
# is model.save() or model.delete() okay here?
```

There are probably other quirky cases where .only() and .defer() should be cautioned, I just can't think of any right now. They seem like super useful methods though.. If anyone comes up with any please post, thanks.

Comment: make sure DEBUG=False... I often forget to change this..

Comment: @monkut I can't help but notice that ur blog is hosted at webfaction, those guys are pure awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it would be useful to call `save()` on a model with only the `pk` field. However if you want to delete objects without incurring the overhead of instantiating the objects, you can use the queryset method:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=12).delete()
```

Note that this won't call any custom `delete()` methods you have on the model, but otherwise is much more efficient that getting the instance and calling delete on it.

Answer (score 0):

`only` and `defer` always retrieve the id of the model so the it can be used normally.

However Django's orm has some memory overhead for every query if `DEBUG=True` ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#why-is-django-leaking-memory)).

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve? `reset_queries` is only useful to remove the SQL logged in DEBUG mode. It won't help reduce memory usage in production.

Comment: Fair enough, the code sample wasn't clear/useful in the current context. I've removed it.